# XP no longer booting after resetting Admin password

Tags: windows-xp, boot, passwords

My work group has a few XP machines to control old hardware. We can't use XP mode because, as far as I understand, that won't communicate with PCI cards.

We lost the Administrator password for one of the machines and did not have any other local accounts. I tried simply deleting the Administrator password with the free version of Windows Password Key and now the hard drive no longer boots.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what may be the problem or how to reinstall XP if we don't have available install discs?

Comment: "_now the hard drive no longer boots_" ... what exactly do you mean? I presume you get POST? Do you get the Windows loading/splash screen? etc... Please be more descriptive with the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to access the Recovery Console. At the Command Prompt, run these commands to restore the registry files:

```
copy c:\windows\repair\system c:\windows\system32\config\system
copy c:\windows\repair\software c:\windows\system32\config\software
copy c:\windows\repair\sam c:\windows\system32\config\sam
copy c:\windows\repair\security c:\windows\system32\config\security
copy c:\windows\repair\default c:\windows\system32\config\default
```

([Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307545/how-to-recover-from-a-corrupted-registry-that-prevents-windows-xp-from))